How is voice dissonance allowed in (non classical) counterpoint?
I learned (non classical) counterpoint as one or more additional voice(s) over a main voice that uses the same rhythm, but with 3rd, 5th, possibly 7th on multiple octaves so that the combination of the voices creates a consonant interval.
An exception to this would be when there is silence in the main voice, therefore the counterpoint can be anything both harmonically and rhythmically.
However I have seen such counterpoints that are harmonically correct, but only during the first part of the main voice note duration. Example:

Main voice



A strict counterpoint (one voice)



Another "less strict" counterpoint?


Is this last example allowed, or does it make your counterpoint less "strict"?

I wonder if you mean "counterpoint" or "harmony". Counterpoint would have multiple simultaneous "melodies", but your post only refers to a single melody plus accompaniment.

Also, an example of the sort of technique you're asking about would be very helpful, if not essential, in order to give you the best answer.

I am sure it is about counterpoint, the voices are made to be played simultaneoulsly, but not classical counterpoint that have different sets of "rules"

Where did you get your understanding of the terms you're using? "strict", "modern counterpoint", "consonance", "modulation", etc.

From a book about instrument specific techniques, not a music theory book.

"non-classical counterpoint"? Not sure what that means. Outside of Western classical music, there is no theory of counterpoint.

"or does it make your counterpoint less strict": it depends on which rules you're using.  The "classical" approach calls four-against-one counterpoint "third species" and passing dissonances are more or less guaranteed, but indeed not every passing dissonance is within the rules.

@Aaron Stravinsky's counterpoint, among others, is non-classical counterpoint.

After looking at this question and Michael's answer for a day, I'm going to vote to close as unclear. Michael's answer did a great job at guessing about the many confusing parts of this question, but there shouldn't have to be that much guesswork. I'd recommend editing to quote the book that gave you these terms, since it's using them in its own unusual way.

I'd also suggest that you might enjoy learning about the various "strict" levels of classical counterpoint if you're interested; start with some basic theory if you're not clear on it, and then Google "species counterpoint," maybe throwing in the terms "Fux" or "Gradus ad Parnassum."

@phoog it depends on what one means by classical. I took the question to mean it as a blanket term. However, I wasn’t about to address, for example, serial composition, which, regardless of definitions, is clearly not relevant here.

I'm confused about how you use the musical terms in your question, but I think it might not be helpful to try unravelling that.
When you say "strict counterpoint", I think two things. Fux style species counterpoint where a set of leveled counterpoint exercises are given a student and those exercises must be completed according to strict rules. This is a teaching method, not a composition style.
The second meaning of "strict counterpoint" might be something like imitation between voices, or some other counterpoint procedure (like melodic inversion), where the procedure is applied in an exact, strict way.
Insofar as species counterpoint is strict I would not call it "modern", not the variety characterized by Fux. "Modern" in music connotes styles like those of Stravinsky, Bartok, etc. In modern music counterpoint would not be restricted by any sense of strictness other than some personal scheme imposed by the composer.
This example you gave...

...would not be strict in the sense of species counterpoint, because of the dissonance on the third beat, but the rhythm aspect only, of note durations of 4 against 1, would be Fux's third species.
In a modern style of music the dissonance on beat three would be perfectly fine.

Is voice modulation allowed in counterpoint?

I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Generally, "modulation" means simply "change." To change something. In music, its primary meaning is to "change key." In contrapuntal music you certainly can change key. "Voice modulation" might mean the voice changes pitch, volume, etc. but in a general sense. If your meaning isn't specifically "change key", you needs to say what exactly is changing with a voice.

Is this last example allowed?

Whenever you get into things allowed or not in music, you need to say what methods you are using. Otherwise, anything is allowed, because music is art.
Species counterpoint is one strict method. Fux's Gradus ad Parnassum is the most famous example. You should get a copy of the book, but a nice summary is here: https://tobyrush.com/theorypages/pdf/en-us/species-counterpoint-set.pdf.
Voice leading is another area of music that gets into "rules." Sometimes the topic is called "relative motion." Most textbooks on harmony or counterpoint will lay out the "rules" of voice leading. This wiki article has an ok summary.
The "classical" style that many people associate with "rules" based composition is often referred to as the "common practice era." Composers of that time adhered to certain common practice conventions (rather than rules) to varying degrees where strictness was associated with Church Music and a conservative artistic approach. Modernism often conveys a meaning of not following those strict common practice conventions. It probably goes to far to say modernism means "do whatever you want", some modern styles are more radical than others, but suffice to say it is not adhering to the conventions of Church Music, the common practice era, or species counterpoint.
To get a better understanding of counterpoint, common practice conventions, strictness, etc. and the terminology involved Fux's Gradus ad Parnassum is probably where you want to start, along with a college textbook on general harmony. Make sure your study of counterpoint includes at the beginning something covering good melody. Counterpoint textbooks by Piston and Keenan offer overviews of melody. "How to write a cantus firmus" is another topic to explore for a general understanding of melody. (The Toby Rush PDF linked above includes a melody review.)
Finally, if you want to compare common practice era counterpoint with modern counterpoint, you might like to compare Bach's Well Tempered Clavier from 1722 with Shostakovich's 24 Preludes and Fugues from c. 1950. I think this could be a good way to make the style comparison, because Shostakovich's work obviously parallels Bach's, but especially in regard to dissonance/consonance and notions of what is "allowed" you can hear the free approach (not strict) treatment of dissonance in the modern music.

This answer globaly illustrate what I was wondering about, but with other examples. My second example is therefore just another style of counterpoint.
